# facebook php sdk does not work. why?

Tags: php, facebook

I create facebook app

```
  require_once("facebook.php");

  $config = array();
  $config[‘appId’] = 'myid';
  $config[‘secret’] = 'mysecret';
  $config[‘fileUpload’] = false; // optional

  $facebook = new Facebook($config);

  $uid = $facebook->getUser();
  echo $uid;
```

but it does not work. I see nothing on my app page! Why?

Comment: I hope that's not your real `appId` and `secret`...?

Comment: Do yourself a massive favour and remove the real `appId` and `secret` from your post. Then flag your question for moderator attention and ask them to remove the sensitive data from the revision history. And take down the image that you've linked to which confirms your confidential data!!!!! It's called `secret` for a reason ;)

Comment: it's just app for test. real app will be with another id and secret. I just whant to know why does not work php sdk?

Comment: You don't appear to understand what Clive is getting at here. Don't post _any_ secret keys, passwords or other sensitive data on the internet. Just don't.

Comment: deleted it and run new namespace and generate new secret on facebook

Answer (score 1):

you may see nothing for a number of reason. One might be that $uid is not a string, but an object and php is throwing an error. You could turn error reporting on and find the error.
also it might be worthwhile doing a var_dump or print_r on uid, uid might not be what you expect

Comment: var_dump or print_r displays nothing too. it seems, like $uid is empty... but why? way to sdk is true, myid and secret code withought errors too.

Comment: if there is still no errors then have a look at the facebook sdk docs. i havent used them recently, but im sure you need to session_start. maybe even session_destroy