# No Facebook User ID returned. Why?

Tags: php, facebook, kohana, kohana-3

I'm new to the [Facebook SDK for PHP](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/). I have a really basic question here ([this answer was not helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8121957/facebook-php-sdk-does-not-work-why)): I am currently logged into my Facebook profile, however, `getUser()` returns nothing. Why?

```
require_once("vendor/facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php");

class Controller_Test extends Controller {
    public function action_me()
        {
            $config = array();
            $config['appId'] = 'dfjq454...';
            $config['secret'] = 'adfw424...';
            $config['fileUpload'] = false;
            $facebook = new Facebook($config);  
            $user = $facebook->getUser();

            // Returns '0'
            echo "Me: ".$user;
            // ...
```

**EDIT 1:**

I tried uncommenting this line in bootstrap.php but it did not work `'auth'       => MODPATH.'auth',       // Basic authentication`

**EDIT 2:**
When I run the following code

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
        echo "My Profile: ".$user_profile;
```

I get this error

> An active access token must be used to query information about the
>   current user.

**EDIT 3**

```
FacebookApiException [ 0 ]: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.
DOCROOT\vendor\facebook-php-sdk\src\base_facebook.php [ 1272 ]
1267    *
1268    * @param $result array A record storing the error message returned
1269    *                      by a failed API call.
1270    */
1271   protected function throwAPIException($result) {
1272     $e = new FacebookApiException($result);
1273     switch ($e->getType()) {
1274       // OAuth 2.0 Draft 00 style
1275       case 'OAuthException':
1276         // OAuth 2.0 Draft 10 style
1277       case 'invalid_token':
DOCROOT\vendor\facebook-php-sdk\src\base_facebook.php [ 881 ] » BaseFacebook->throwAPIException(arguments)
{PHP internal call} » BaseFacebook->_graph(arguments)
DOCROOT\vendor\facebook-php-sdk\src\base_facebook.php [ 654 ] » call_user_func_array(arguments)
APPPATH\classes\Controller\test.php [ 17 ] » BaseFacebook->api(arguments)
SYSPATH\classes\Kohana\Controller.php [ 84 ] » Controller_Test->action_me()
{PHP internal call} » Kohana_Controller->execute()
SYSPATH\classes\Kohana\Request\Client\Internal.php [ 97 ] » ReflectionMethod->invoke(arguments)
SYSPATH\classes\Kohana\Request\Client.php [ 114 ] » Kohana_Request_Client_Internal->execute_request(arguments)
SYSPATH\classes\Kohana\Request.php [ 986 ] » Kohana_Request_Client->execute(arguments)
DOCROOT\index.php [ 118 ] » Kohana_Request->execute()
```

Comment: Is your app configured as a Native/Desktop app? That might cause this issue.

Comment: +1 Thank you for your reply. How do I check whether my app is configured as a Native app? I searched the bootstrap.php file but did not see any such setting.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Facebook Developer documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/):

> Note: Applications that are configured as Native/Desktop apps will not be able to make API calls that require an application access_token.

Go to Settings →  Advanced, and change it to `Web`:

[image]

That's the most common cause for this issue and changing it to `Web` should solve it.

---

If that wasn't the case, it's probably an issue with PHP SDK, which relies on `$_REQUEST` super-global array from the server which has changed in PHP 5.4.x because of default `php.ini` settings having been changed. A work-around  <sup>[`source`](https://www.webniraj.com/2012/12/19/facebook-php-sdk-fixing-getuser-on-php-5-4-x/)</sup>  is to imitate `$_REQUEST` used in `base_facebook.php` with `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE` super-global arrays.

Find the following code in your `base_facebook.php`:

```
<?php

protected function getCode() {
    if (isset($_REQUEST['code'])) {
        if ($this->state !== null &&
                isset($_REQUEST['state']) &&
                $this->state === $_REQUEST['state']) {

            // CSRF state has done its job, so clear it
            $this->state = null;
            $this->clearPersistentData('state');
            return $_REQUEST['code'];
        } else {
            self::errorLog('CSRF state token does not match one provided.');
            return false;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

?>
```

Change it to:

```
<?php

protected function getCode() {
    $server_info = array_merge($_GET, $_POST, $_COOKIE);

    if (isset($server_info['code'])) {
        if ($this->state !== null &&
                isset($server_info['state']) &&
                $this->state === $server_info['state']) {

            // CSRF state has done its job, so clear it
            $this->state = null;
            $this->clearPersistentData('state');
            return $server_info['code'];
        } else {
            self::errorLog('CSRF state token does not match one provided.');
            return false;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

?>
```

**[See the difference.](http://www.diffchecker.com/wwe023r0)**

Comment: +1 Thank you for your guidance to the advanced settings. It's already set to web though. However, I noticed the message: `This app is in sandbox mode (only visible to Admins, Developers and Testers)`.

Comment: @Anthony: What is the PHP version / PHP SDK version?

Comment: +1 My PHP version is 5.4.16. However, I'm still trying to find the version number for Facebook SDK for PHP. I downloaded it only yesterday... how do I get this version number?

Comment: Facebook PHP SDK (v.3.2.2) I got this info in the readme.md file

Comment: +1 I searched for `base_config.php` (using Windows search feature) in my WAMP directory, the Facebook SDK directory, and the Kohana directory. It was not found. Can it go by a different name?

Comment: @Anthony: Sorry, it was a typo. I meant `base_facebook.php`.

Comment: +1 Thank you very much for the helpful diff checker (http://www.diffchecker.com/wwe023r0) . I double checked it, but I'm still getting this error `FacebookApiException [ 0 ]: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.` see edit 3 in my question above for the full error message.

Comment: I noticed in `base_facebook.php` that there was a `$_REQUEST` in `public function getSignedRequest()`. Do I have to change that as well as all other occurences of `$_REQUEST` as well?

Comment: @Anthony: yes, change all the occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck up with similar issue, here is the solution that may help you.

```
 $facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => 'xxxx',
    'secret' => 'xxxxx',
    "redirect_uri" => "set the uri to point to the same page"
 ));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if($user)
{
//your task
} else {
header('location:'. $facebook->getLoginUrl());

}

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if($user)
{
 //your task
} else {
header('location:'. $facebook->getLoginUrl());

}
```